# How to hide inherited fields in the custom list definition?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, list-definition

I have defined a Site Content Type which has inherited fields (inherited from parent content type). Also, created new custom list definition that uses the content type created. I want to hide the inherited fields in the list definition.

I tried setting `ShowinEditForm, ShowinDisplayForm, ShowinViewForm` all to "**FALSE**", but it continues to be visible. How do I make it invisible in the list definition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Inherits` attribute to `False` in child content type. Then add those fields which need to be hidden in the `FieldRefs` section using `RemoveFieldRef`. See this for more information: 
http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2011/06/hide-parent-field-in-child-content-type.html

**UPDATE**

In the Schema.xml file, define the field and set its visibility properties.
Example:

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="UserAccountRequestListDef" ModerationType="TRUE" ModeratedList="TRUE" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" DisableAttachments="TRUE" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/UserAccountRequestListDef" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" NavigateForFormsPages="FALSE">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentType ID="0x01001a148caa96674ad1ae7da45d6964cbb1008f4a465fc6204289b4c51af92860e622" Name="UserAccountRequest" Group="User Content Types" Description="Use this to request a new client account" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0">
        <FieldRefs>             
          <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" DisplayName="Last Name"/>
          <FieldRef ID="{E63469D9-EEF3-4A8B-A4B6-54250CC30509}" Name="DeactivateAccount" DisplayName="Deactivate" />
          <FieldRef ID="{607391AC-7F89-40CF-A354-1DA661F16365}" Name="AccountState" DisplayName="Account State" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </ContentType>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
        <Field ID="{607391AC-7F89-40CF-A354-1DA661F16365}"
             Name="AccountState"
             Type="Choice"
             DisplayName="Account State"
             Required="TRUE"
             EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"
             Indexed="FALSE"
             Format="RadioButtons"
             FillInChoice="FALSE"
             ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE"
             ShowInEditForm="FALSE"
             ShowInFileDlg="FALSE"
             ShowInListSettings="FALSE"
             ShowInNewForm="FALSE"
             ShowInVersionHistory="FALSE"
             ShowInViewForms="FALSE"
             StaticName="AccountState"
             Sealed="TRUE">
        <Default>New</Default>
        <CHOICES>
          <CHOICE>New</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>Active</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>Inactive</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
      </Field>
    </Fields>
```

Comment: Nadeem, Thanks for the response! But I do not want to remove the field from the child content type. I just want to hide it in the List definition that uses this content type. The reason is that in the future the application might extend and these fields(fields that I am trying to hide) might be used. Hence removal is not an option. Is this possible?

What does a field OverWrite element do? Can I use that?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: I tried setting the visibility properties and it didn't help. The field continues to be visible in all forms.                                                <Field Type="Note" DisplayName="Description" Required="FALSE" Hidden="FALSE" ID="{bbb1f503-cf52-47c3-8e43-cc8ac71ef4bb}" Name="Description1"  ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" ShowInListSettings="FALSE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInVersionHistory="FALSE" ShowInViewForms="FALSE"/>